# Authorization returns false in Form Request

Tags: php, laravel, authorization

In a form request, I need to check whether a user can update or not a `Vehicle`. I have the following method:

```
public function authorize()
{
    $vehicle = Vehicle::find($this->route('vehicle'));

    return $vehicle and $this->user()->can('update', $vehicle);
}
```

I checked with `dd` and `$this->user()->can('update', $vehicle)` returns `false` even if I put the return value of the `update` policy to `true`. I tried the policy in a controller and I had no issue. It's like the `can` method can't find the `update` policy while it is registered.

Why does not it work?

Comment: `dd($vehicle)` is returning the correct model?

Comment: Just check and it returns an Array. Why do I get an array when doing exactly like in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#authorizing-form-requests)?

Comment: An array of what?

Comment: An array with one vehicle. So with `$vehicle[0]` it works, but it's not like the documentation.

Comment: @Wizix check the answer it's a bug if it is returning array! However shouldn't `and` be `&&` as per docs? or it doesn't matter?

Comment: are you having a policy that is registered at the authservice provider for this?

Comment: @Iftikharuddin the issue seems to come from the `Vehicle::find()` method.

Comment: @spartyboy Yes.

Comment: i noticed u used $this->route('vehicle') this would give you your url path the find method only works with the primary key of a column, if that doesn't work do make sure your user model implements the authorizable trait

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an issue I saw a long time ago when using route() in the pull for the class - it seems to pull an array.  As you said this is not what is reflected in the documentation.

Take a look at the Laravel [bug report here](https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/issues/119).

There are potential work-arounds if this is indeed your issue.  Quoted from the issue page (insert vehicle for user, or whatever):

```
$route = $request->route();
$user_id = is_array($route) ? $route[2]['user_id'] : $route->parameter('user_id');
```

Pretty ugly, I know.  But you could also change your architecture slightly and pull the id in like you would in a normal controller method if you wanted, sort of like:

```
public function myNewPreAuthThing(Request $request, $id){}
```

And then send the correct id through to the auth.  Either way it's not clean, I know.  But... I think you have hit on a know bug.

Comment: I found the actual issue. The documentation seems just to be wrong. Using `$vehicle = Vehicle::find($this->route('vehicle')->id);` I have absolutely no issue, the `find` method use the `id` of a model to find it in the database. As I was giving it an entire model instead of an id, it just returned an array containing the response. No?

Comment: Possibly, yes.  It would depend on what your incoming route said (IE if you were using route-model binding, then the above works).  Also if you were using Laravel 5.6 or below, then the above bug is definitely a problem.  However, it would likely manifest differently -- it would most likely return a null object (find on an array wouldn't work).   If I understand your original issue though, it looked like it was returning the *object as an array* and id happened to be the first param.  For these reasons, I tend to use auth in a function like my last bit above - it is pretty bullet proof